# JAVA_HOME path for ant run command

Tags: java, contiki, ubuntu-20.04, cooja, contiki-ng

I am trying to install contiki-ng in my system and everything has proceeded well, until I try to run the `ant run` command in `contiki-ng/tools/cooja` directory, upon which I get the following response:

> We cannot run Java, please ensure you have Java installed.
> We have tried to execute /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java/bin/java but failed.
> If you have installed Java in a unusual place you can set JAVA_HOME
> to the directory containing the Java installation.

I realized that I had to change `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java/bin/java` to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java` (remove /bin/java from the end; I had copied the path wrong) in the .bashrc file.

Even after doing that, I am still getting the same error. Can someone help?

Comment: hmmm.. can you put the content of the script you ran in here? and just to make sure, have you tried to reload the env? `source .bashrc`

Comment: See https://github.com/contiki-ng/contiki-ng/issues/1046

Comment: Best use the Contiki-NG Docker image. It has everything preinstalled and working. Getting Java set up has always been a bit of nightmare for those of us who are not enterprise programmers.

Answer (score 3):

you should have JAVA_HOME set to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64` because it should point to java home directory, not bin directory

Comment: No matter what I change the JAVA_HOME to, running `ant run` doesn't show any different error message. I even restarted the shell and tried, but to no avail

Comment: it is difficult to give you more help when I don't have other information. Check if you have JAVA_HOME really set (e.g run `export | grep JAVA_HOME` command) or run `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64 ant run`
Also check if your ant version is supporting java 11